# Installing Fedora on VMWare error: CPU disabled by guest operating system

Tags: fedora, vmware

When I try to install Fedora 16 on VMWare I'm getting the error CPU has been disabled by guest operating system. Any clues?

Comment: You will have to provide much more information for this to be answerable. To start with: which variant and version of VMware, which version and architecture of Fedora 16, what host OS and architecture, where is the error message displayed, and what are the VM settings?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [limitation of older versions of VMware](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/409417). Upgrade to Workstation 8 or later, or ESXi 5.0 or later.